# Why do we pray to be saved from Ayin Hara if we don't believe in it?

Tags: halacha, mysticism-kabbalah

The Gemara says in [Pesachim 110b](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.110b.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> כְּלָלָא דְמִילְּתָא כׇּל דְּקָפֵיד קָפְדִי בַּהֲדֵיהּ וּדְלָא קָפֵיד לָא קָפְדִי בַּהֲדֵיהּ וּמִיהוּ לְמֵיחַשׁ מִיבְּעֵי.
>
> The general rule is that anyone who is particular about them (drinking in pairs), the demons are particular with him, and anyone who is not particular, the demons are not particular with him.

R Moshe Feinstein (Igros Moshe Even Ha'Ezer 3:26) says that the Gemara is applicable in regard to Ayin Hara too.

How would he understand the fact that we pray every day after the morning Brachos

> יְהִי רָצון מִלְּפָנֶיךָ ה' אֱלהַי וֵאלהֵי אֲבותַי שֶׁתַּצִּילֵנִי הַיּום וּבְכָל יום מֵעַזֵּי פָנִים וּמֵעַזּוּת פָּנִים. מֵאָדָם רָע. מִיֵּצֶר רָע. וּמֵחָבֵר רָע. וּמִשָּׁכֵן
> 'רָע. וּמִפֶּגַע רָע. **מֵעַיִן הָרָע** וכו

Comment: See Rashbam’s approach there with regard to zugot. Don’t go overboard, but still worth being slightly wary. Maybe this falls into the same category

Comment: Is the first “we” identical to the second?

Comment: There may be a difference to deliberately giving someone an *ayin ha'ra* and between receiving an ambient type of *lashon ha'ra*. In the first case, your attitude will not help you (and this is a *ma'aseh mazik*), Reb Moshe's *sevara* applied to the second case.

Comment: You didn't translate the last three words וּמִיהוּ לְמֵיחַשׁ מִיבְּעֵי

Comment: Doesn't the gemara there itself say.. you still have to be choshesh for it?

Comment: Ayin Hara has 2 meanings. One is referring to some spiritual force, and one literally means that people will look at you in a negative light. I think the prayer in the morning is referring to the latter.